# Running a long process on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Say I have a laptop and an Ubuntu server. There is a heavy task that I want to perform on Ubuntu server.

So far, I connected to the server through SSH and perform it. However, when I need to shut down the laptop (leaving the office), the SSH session is lost and I have no idea what is going on with the process.

Is there a solution that I can let the process run on Ubuntu server, and tomorrow morning when I turn my laptop on I can resume checking what's happening with the process?

Comment: Loook into `nohup` and `tmux` - they do different things, but both will achiave what you're after here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use screen command on server.
You need to install related package if not present on server

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

1. create screen

   ```
   screen
   ```
2. execute command you want to run in that screen
3. come out of the screen by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>
4. list the screen

   ```
   # screen -ls
   ```
5. You can now come of out ssh session as your command is running in screen
6. ssh again and attach the screen to check the command status

   ```
   screen -r screen_name
   ```

Comment: ``screen`` does not work if I restart my laptop I think

Comment: You need to run `screen` on the server, not your laptop

Comment: do you want to run a task on remote server or on your local laptop? These steps are for server. You need to ssh your server follow the steps. So command will be executing on server even if you terminate ssh session.

Answer (score 2):

Start your command with `nohup`: `nohup {command} {args...}` and often reroute the output to file:`nohup {command} {args...} >{logfile}`.

Among other things `nohup` prevents your command from receiving the SIGHUP signal that tells it its parent disconnected.

If you reconnect and want to check the output, do `tail -f {logfile}`.

Comment: Many thanks. And how can I reconnect to check the process?

Comment: See improved answer...

Answer (score 0):

I usually run the task in background and log output to files, checking progress by "tailing" my logs:

```
$> my_long_task.sh > stdout.log 2> stderr.log &
```

And when I want to check the status I do:

```
$> tail stdout.log
$> tail stderr.log
```